# Removing strong tag and re-bolding matches chars in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bold all matches characters in button strings on changing in `input`. The function, however, is working fine only on the first letter of search and is not adding the `<strong></strong>` to the string when there are more than one string matches.

I tried to unwrap the matched strings on `keyup` using any of the following solutions to reapply the strong to matched strings but this is not working either:

```
$("button").find('strong').unwrap('strong');
$("button").children().unwrap('strong');
$("button").children().find('strong').unwrap();
```

```js
$("input").on('keyup', function() {
  // $("button").find('strong').unwrap('strong');
  // $("button").children().unwrap('strong');
  // $("button").children().find('strong').unwrap();

  var boldLetter = $("input").val();
  $("button").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(new RegExp(boldLetter, 'gi'), '<strong>$&</strong>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter Search Word: <input type="text">
<br />
<br />
<button type="button">Afghanistan</button>
<button type="button">Antarctica</button>
<button type="button">Mali</button>
<button type="button">Canada</button>
<button type="button">US</button>
<button type="button">France</button>
<button type="button">Chile</button>
<button type="button">Peru</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to unwrap the `<strong>`, you want to unwrap *the text **within** the `<strong>`*. You can specify this using [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
$("button strong").contents().unwrap('strong');
```

```js
$("input").on('keyup', function() {
  
  $("button").find('strong').contents().unwrap();

  var boldLetter = $("input").val();
  if (!boldLetter) return;  //Don't perform regex replace if input is empty
  
  $("button").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(new RegExp(boldLetter, 'gi'), '<strong>$&</strong>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter Search Word: <input type="text">
<br />
<br />
<button type="button">Afghanistan</button>
<button type="button">Antarctica</button>
<button type="button">Mali</button>
<button type="button">Canada</button>
<button type="button">US</button>
<button type="button">France</button>
<button type="button">Chile</button>
<button type="button">Peru</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, this is kindda working. Can you please Enter `a` then clear the text with `Backspace` and then again go with `an` this time the bold is not working

Comment: @MonaCoder Admittedly I'd noticed that, however I thought it may just be a side effect of your snippet. I can edit the answer to address this.

Comment: I just noticed the issue testing your code and you are right it is happening on initial code too. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lots Tyler